# C++ Primer paragraph on Integer literals, need someone to clarify some points

Tags: c++, types, literals

I'm currently working through C++ Primer (5th Edition), and I'm struggling trying to figure out what the author means in this part on literals (Chapter 2, section 2.1.3):

> *... By default, decimal literals are signed whereas octal and hexadecimal literals can be either signed or unsigned types. A decimal literal has the smallest type of int, long, or long long (i.e., the first type in this list) in which the literal’s value fits. Octal and hexadecimal literals have the smallest type of int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, long long, or unsigned long long in which the literal’s value fits. It is an error to use a literal that is too large to fit in the largest related type...*

In the first sentence, does the author mean that decimal literals are signed according to the C++ standard, and for octal and hexadecimal literals it depends on the compiler?

The next three sentences really confuse me though, so if someone could offer an alternative explaination, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A literal has a value. The integral types can only accept values within some range. The paragraph is basically saying the type of the literal is the smallest one that can accept the value (within the list, which is different for decimal literals vs. the other integral literals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an integer literal for example a decimal integer literal the compiler has to define its type. For example a decimal literal can be used in expressions and the compiler need to determine the type of an expression based on the types of its operands.

So for decimal integer literals the compiler selects between the following types

```
int
long int
long long int
```

and choices the first type that can accomodate the decimal literal.

It does not consider unsigned integer types as for example unsigned int or unsigned long int though they could accomodate a given literal.

The situation is different when the compiler deals with octal or hexadecimal integer literals. In this case it considers the following types in the given order

```
int
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

That it would be more clear consider an artificial example to demonstrate the idea. Let's assume that you have a value equal to `127`. This value can be stored in type `signed char`. Now what about value `128`?  It can not be stored in an object of type `signed char` because the maximum positive value that can be stored in an object of type `signed char` is 127.

What to do? We could store `128` in an object of type `unsigned char` because its maximum value is `255`. However the compiler prefers to store it in an object of type `signed short`.

But if this value was specified like `0x80` then the compiler would select an object of type `unsigned char`

It is of course an imaginary process.

However in realty a similar algorithm is used for decimal literals only the compiler takes into account integer types starting from `int` that to determine the type of a decimal literal.

Answer (score 3):

Decimal (meaning base-10) literals are those that have no prefix. The author is saying that these are always signed.

```
5      // signed int (decimal)
12     // signed int (decimal)
```

They can also be signed or unsigned based on either you providing a suffix. [Here's a full reference for integer literal syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

```
5      // signed int
7U     // unsigned int
7UL    // unsigned long
```

Hex (base-8) values will be prefixed with `0x`.

```
0x05   // int (hex)
```

Similarly octal (base-8) values are prefixed with `0`.

```
05     // int (octal)
```

Answer (score 1):

To append to Cory's answer:

The relevant diagram in the link states

### Types allowed for integer literals

#### No suffix, regular decimal

```
int, long int, long long int(since C++11)
```

So the decimal number

```
78625723
```

Is represented by a signed type.

#### No suffix hexadecimal or octal bases

```
int, long int, 
unsigned int, unsigned long int
long long int(since C++11)
unsigned long long int(since C++11)
```

So the 0x hex number

```
0x78625723
```

Might be represented by a signed or an unsigned value.

Answer (score 1):

The place this is relevant is when you have literal values that are just a little too big to fit in a signed type, but do fit in the corresponding unsigned type.  For example, on a machine with 16-bit `int` and 32-bit `long` (rare these days, but the minimum allowed by the spec), the constant literal `0xffff` will be an `unsigned int`, while the literal `65535` (same value) will be a `long`.

Of course, you can force the latter to be an `unsigned` by using a `U` suffix; this part of the spec is only relevant for literals with no suffix.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why decimal and non-decimal integers differ like this?